# Passing very large array from solidity to web3

Tags: web3js, arrays

I have a large data array in the BC.
The array has 15,000,000 items of `Car` `struct`

```
struct Car{
 string tag;
 uint mileage;
 string make;
 string model;
 address address;
 string country;
}
```

I need to search for a:
specific model and
millage between X , Y and
country equals to X and
tag starts with a specific letter
(it gets more complicated).

Do you think its a good practice to pass back to WEB3 15M items and search in JS?
Doing this search in solidity will cost a lot of gas. and JS will be easier to search in.

How fast will WEB3 return this amount of rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That sounds hairy.

Did the `Car` insertion emit an event with the relevant information? If yes, then you can `.watch` it from the block of the first insertion. This would:

- help you reduce the memory cost in Javascript
- allow you to "restart" from a more recent block whenever it crashed

Have a look at [RxJs](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html) on how to transform an event watcher into an Observable. Then you can apply filters and such, which would help you.

Something like this not so pseudo-code:

```
Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
        const filter = myContract.LogCar();

        filter.watch((err, oneEvent) => {
            if (err) observer.onError(err)
            else observer.onNext(oneEvent);
        });

        // Cleanup logic
        return () => filter.stopWatching(console.error);
    })
    .filter(oneEvent => oneEvent.args.mileage.atLeast(10))
    .subscribe(
        console.log,
        console.error,
        () => console.log("completed"));
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain how an event can help with that? what happens when someone enters a new search query, all the events already fired. please explain. thanks

Comment: If you want to run a search query, the blockchain itself is the wrong data structure. To run a search query, you need to import all the events into a specialised search engine. To extract all the events, you can use the same code as above, minus the filter.